# php pdo informix returns data as string or NULL

Tags: php, pdo, informix

data from informix with PDO Informix are always returned as string, only NULL is returned as NULL.

I have tried playing with

```
$pdo_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);
```

to no success. Also, when I try

```
$pdo_conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES);
```

I get PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support that attribute

I use

```
  $prep = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
  $prep->execute();
  $result = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Anyone out there knows how to get my float as a float with pdo informix?

Thanks,
Arie.

Comment: This is 100% driver specific. If the driver doesn't support it, you're out of luck. (I've never used Informix so I can't tell whether it's the case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Informix PDO driver returns everything as a PDO_PARAM_STR (except CLOBs which are returned as PDO_PARAM_LOB).

Same as the PDO_ODBC, for every column in the resulset, the driver uses SQL_C_CHAR for the internal SQLBindCol ODBC call.

The value of the ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES attribute makes no difference as the returned data type is already a string.
You can check the driver source code (around line 653):

https://github.com/php/pecl-database-pdo_informix/blob/master/informix_statement.c

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea on why they would do that? What is the use of floats and ints if everything is returned as a string I wonder... Even the point in the float is not returned, it is a string of numbers without a dot. This is pretty useless?

Comment: I guess it is simpler to return everything as a string and let the application to do the conversion if needed. Keep in mind that there are lots of data types in Informix (and other databases) which may not exists at all in PHP. Mostly everything can be written as a string (including decimals).  I tried a simple `select 1.123456789::float from...` and I get `1.123456789` returned

Comment: After trying your suggestion I come to the conclusion that it has to do with DB_LOCALE and CLIENT_LOCALE. When I use squirrel SQL (jdbc driver) with `DB_LOCALE=en_us.1252;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_us.1252@dict;` it returns a comma for the floating point, as is normal in Belgium. Any idea how to return it as a dot using CLIENT_LOCALE? In the meanwhile I am searching for the answer...

Comment: That's normal (I mean, it's something I have seen before when the regional settings are not right).  The period (.)  is taken as the thousand separator rather than the decimal, that's why you don't see anything other than digits. The first part of CLIENT_LOCALE/DB_LOCALE sets your locale settings. en_US means English in US territory (which uses period and comma for decimal/thousands). Try setting CLIENT_LOCALE to nl_be.1252, it may work.

Comment: I tackled the problem, and I should have looked better. That said: we apparently have a lot of tables with float columns that are not used to store a float, they only contain integers. Ints > 999 come out with a comma, that is why I wrongly thought that the floating point came out as a comma. So, jsagrera, your answer still was helpful: now I know the bevaviour of pdo_informix better. Thanks.